# Create table by combination two another table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, m

I have two tables

| TAB1 |
| --- |
| Ball |
| Car |

| TAB2 |
| --- |
| Jan |
| Feb |

How join then to get:

| TAB3 |  |
| --- | --- |
| Ball | Jan |
| Car | Jan |
| Ball | Feb |
| Carl | Feb |

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom column and write the name of the other query. Expand the table. This is a Cartesian product.